# Android Nested Recylcerview with different items counts

Tags: android, nestedrecyclerview

I have a nested recyclerview, and I just want it to display different item numbers for each item of the parent recyclerview.

It's supposed that each item implements number of view according to each model object list that's been passed to adapter

[It may look like as the layout shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV4VM.png)

Here is my parent adapter code

```
public class ConstructionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ConstructionAdapter.ConstructionViewHolder> {

private RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool viewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();
private final List<ConstructionModel> constructionList;

public ConstructionAdapter(List<ConstructionModel> constructionList) {
    this.constructionList = constructionList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ConstructionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.construction_cranes_view_item, parent, false);

    return new ConstructionViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ConstructionViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.setContent(constructionList.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return constructionList.size();
}

public class ConstructionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView categoeyTitleTV;
    private RecyclerView constructionRecyclerView;

    private ConstructionViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        categoeyTitleTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_title_tv);
        constructionRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.construction_item_recycler);
    }

    private void setContent(ConstructionModel model) {
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(itemView.getContext());
        constructionRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        categoeyTitleTV.setText(model.getCraneCategory());
        layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(model.getSubCategoryList().size());
        IndustrialCranesAdapter subCatAdapter = new IndustrialCranesAdapter(model.getSubCategoryList());
        constructionRecyclerView.setAdapter(subCatAdapter);
        constructionRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);

    }
}
```

}

Here is my Inner recyclerview adapter

```
public class IndustrialCranesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<IndustrialCranesAdapter.IndustrialCranesViewHolder> {
private final List<Crane> industrialCranesList;

public IndustrialCranesAdapter(List<Crane> industrialCranesList) {
    this.industrialCranesList = industrialCranesList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public IndustrialCranesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.crane_item, parent, false);

    return new IndustrialCranesViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull IndustrialCranesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setCranesItems(industrialCranesList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return industrialCranesList.size();
}

public class IndustrialCranesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView craneTitle;
    private ImageView craneImage;

    private IndustrialCranesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        craneTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.industrial_crane_title);
        craneImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.industrial_crane_image_view);
        
        itemView.getRootView().setOnClickListener(v->{
            Toast.makeText(itemView.getContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
    }
    private void setCranesItems(Crane crane){
        craneTitle.setText(crane.getCraneTitle());
        craneImage.setImageResource(crane.getCraneImage());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I recommend you use a sectioned list. One adapter and one recyclerview. Simply to use! see this: https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2019/07/18/android-simple-section-recylerview/

Comment: So what is the error you get from above code?

Comment: @lolloCreator Thaaaanks, that is I was looking for, you saved my time ♥

Comment: @Changer I was getting the all items implemented in each item of the inner recyclerview, but with LolloCreato's answer I got to control how many items should each item has.